# Insert/create user in database using login form

Tags: 7, users

I know its dump question, using login form and insert user in database.

Actually, I have an API that includes users of company/organization and these users already have registered on other applications. So, using such API I can get user info using username and password.

Of course, we need to logged in users directly (without registration) who already have account on other applications.

For logging in, I need to, first, insert the user info in data (before insertion, I can fetch username and password from API) so user can get in the site as logged in user.

- **After fetching from API, how to create user in the database with
  username and password field only?**
- **It should be done without email info.**

Comment: `mail` is a required property, you can't have a Drupal account without an email address

Comment: It can be done without email address. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my question requirements, it can be done by using the [user_external_login_register](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7.x) and [user_external_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_load/7.x) Drupal APIs. See the custom module below for more understanding. I hope this will help someone who needs the same requirement(s).

```
<?php
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
*/
function hook_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    _subscribe_user_login_form_alter($form, $form_state);
}
function _subscribe_user_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $saveForm = $form;
    $form = array();
    // overrides the default validator
    foreach( $saveForm as $key => $value ) {
        if( $key == '#validate' ) {
            $form[ $key ] = array();
            foreach( $value as $validator ) {
                if( $validator == 'user_login_authenticate_validate' ) {
                    $validator = 'MODULENAME_authenticate_validate';
                }
            $form[ $key ][] = $validator;
            }
        } else {
            $form[ $key ] = $value;
        }
    }
}

function MODULENAME_authenticate_validate( $form, &$form_state ) {
    $name = $form_state[ 'values' ][ 'name' ];
    $pass = $form_state[ 'values' ][ 'pass' ];
    // use Drupal authentication for this user
    if ($name == 'admin'){
        return user_login_authenticate_validate($form, $form_state);
    }
    $authenticated = api_check_user($name, $pass);
    if ($authenticated == TRUE){
        //save external user if don't exist
        user_external_login_register($name, "MODULENAME");
        // we must set the 'uid' to pass back.  this looks up the logged in user and sets the Drupal UID
        $account = user_external_load($name);
        $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
        drupal_set_message(t('an error has occured'));
    }else{
        drupal_set_message('Error displayed'); // do nothing, Drupal will handle the errors
    }
}
function api_check_user($name, $pass){
    //write code to authenticate user from API
    //if username and password match then API returns true/false
    //if we get true
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a user account in Drupal without writing an email account.

An example of how you can create a user programmatically is:

```
 $new_user = array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'mail' => 'name@email.com',
  'pass' => 'password', // note: do not md5 the password
  'status' => 1
 );

 //custom fields
 $new_user->field_name_lasname['und'][0]['value'] = 'Name and Last Name';
 //custom fields ( custom fields) 
 $new_user->field_referenced_field_['und'][0]['target_id'] = 0;

 user_save(null, $new_user);
```

Please excuse me my English is not good

Comment: It can be done without email address. See my answer